# RxJava without RxAndroid in Android project

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

How to replace RxAndroid `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` to use RxJava only in Android project ?

Comment: Ummm... use some other scheduler. See the RxJava `Schedulers` class.

Comment: can use Looper.getMainLooper() as described in (Communicating with the UI Thread) https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html . But I will wait for answers and suggestions

Comment: won't work then and your code will run in java based background thread only

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you want to do it, but sure you can copy implementation of the 2 Android-specific schedulers from it - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/tree/2.x/rxandroid/src/main/java/io/reactivex/android/schedulers